# Using Jbuilder, Not able to get Json output instead of that showing error like undefined method `dump' for MultiJson:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Please find here is my controller and json file
//controller file

```
module Api
  module V1
   class CouponsController < ApplicationController
     respond_to :json 
     def show
       @coupon = Coupon.find(params[:id])
       render "/coupons/show.json.jbuilder"
    end
   end
 end
end
```

//show.json.jbuilder

```
json.extract! @coupon, :id, :category
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to rewrite the head in controller like this:

```
module Api::V1::CouponsController < ApplicationController
```

Because your current write assumes that you have `Api::V1::ApplicationController`. And `Api::V1::CouponsController` is inherited from it, not from `ApplicationController`.